# Converting datetime in millisec with timezone info

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I have one simple question. How to achieve this format of date `1438117140000+0300`. First part `1438117140000` its the time in millisec , that i convert with no problem, second part with timezone info is my headache , how to get it ??

Comment: what is the meaning of `+0300` in your example? is it the offset from GMT?

Comment: that format makes little sense to me. the timestamp is always expected to be UTC.

Comment: because `1438117140000+0300` and `1438117140000` are 2 different dates (3 hours apart)

Comment: @njzk2, they are not two different `Date`s, because the timezone information is not part of a `Date`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic that will probably depend on how you intend to parse the date, but I don't see why someone would add the timezone to a representation of a date, if not to use it when parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.format` for this purpose:

```
Date now = new Date();
System.out.println(String.format("%tQ%tz", now, now));
```

Executing the code just printed out this:

```
1438635740416+0300
```

The conversions for date/time are specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt). Here, I've used the following two conversion characters:

> 'Q':  Milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch starting at 1
> January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, i.e. Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE.
>
> 'z':  RFC 822 style numeric time zone offset from GMT, e.g. -0800. This
> value will be adjusted as necessary for Daylight Saving Time. For
> long, Long, and Date the time zone used is the default time zone for
> this instance of the Java virtual machine.

Comment: so that actually does not represent the `now` date.

Comment: @njzk2, it represents the `now` date in the current timezone of the JVM. Or what do you mean?

Comment: `1438635740416` is now. +0300 is 3 hours from now.

Comment: You must be deliberately ignorant of time zones.

Comment: `0` represents 01/01/1970 00:00 UTC. `0+0300` represents 31/12/1969 21:00 UTC, just like `01/01/1970 00:00+0300` does.

Comment: No. The last four digits (the `z` conversion) correspond to a _timezone offset_, as specified by RFC 822 / [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC). Quoting wikipedia: The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30".

Comment: my point exactly. `21:00 UTC` == `00:00+0300`. giving a timestamp in utc then adding then timezone messes things up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like +0300 means +3 hours from GMT. so convert 0300 (3 hours) to milliseconds and add to 1438117140000. then convert to a date time as you are already

Answer (score 0):

Split the value you have to '+' then add 3 hours as miliseconds to the first value of the array that split method returned.